# Tensorflow DNNClassifier predictions as array

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

Any advice is welcome as this is an ambitious second coding project. :)
Specifically, I'm having two different issues with this DNN.

1. I can only seem to get it to run 1 of 100 evaluation steps and,
2. Trouble getting meaningful predictions.

At some point it was running all 100 steps of evaluation. I cannot seem to replicate that now for anything. What am I missing?

The data set is for a dice game. The predictions I'm looking for would be in an array of the same shape as the features and labels with a binary prediction for each position in the array.

I have tried different array shapes and depths to the point that I'm all turned around. Perhaps a different estimator is the solution? It throws a `features dictionary '1' not found` if I try to feed one feature/label combination to the predictor; it demands the same set size as the training and test sets.

Is there a way to return predictions in this way?

Example:

```
predict_feature = {'0': [1, 2, 5, 1, 4, 3]} #1's and  5's would be 'keepers'
predict_label = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
desired output = np.array[.91, .12, .89, .92, .06, .15]
```

The features are generated randomly and labels are created via scoring algorithm from the game. They are passed through the below to create the features dictionary and put labels into an array. Similar functions create the evaluation and prediction sets.

```
def train_evaluation_set(features, labels):
    """Creates training input set"""
    feature = {}
    features = [[digit for digit in features[x]] for x in range(len(features))]
    for x in range(len(features)):
        feature.update({"{}".format(x): features[x]})
    label = np.array(labels)
    return feature, label
```

Tensors are then created.

```
def train_input_fn(feature, label, batch_size):
    """Input function for training"""
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(feature), label))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_x).repeat().batch(100)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    feature, label = iterator.get_next()
    return feature, label
```

The estimator is set up thusly:

```
def main(main=None, argv=None):
    # Set feature columns.
    my_feature_columns = []
    for key in feature.keys():
        my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))

    # Instantiate estimator.
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
        hidden_units=[100, 100, 100],
        n_classes=2)

    # Train the Model.
    classifier.train(
        input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(feature, label, batch_size),
        steps=train_steps)

    # Evaluate the model.
    eval_result = classifier.evaluate(
        input_fn=lambda: eval_input_fn(test_feature, test_label, batch_size),
        steps=200)

    print('\nTest set accuracy: {accuracy:0.3f}\n'.format(**eval_result))

    # Generate predictions from the model
    predictions = classifier.predict(
        input_fn=lambda: predict_input_fn(predict_feature, predict_label[0]))

    pp.pprint(next(predictions))
```

From here the training runs smoothly and one evaluation step is completed.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 0.00292182.
WARNING:tensorflow:Casting <dtype: 'float32'> labels to bool.
WARNING:tensorflow:Casting <dtype: 'float32'> labels to bool.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2018-02-20-09:06:14
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp97u0tbvx\model.ckpt-1000
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [1/200]
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2018-02-20-09:06:19
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 1000: accuracy = 0.666667, accuracy_baseline = 0.833333, auc = 0.8, auc_precision_recall = 0.25, average_loss = 0.623973, global_step = 1000, label/mean = 0.166667, loss = 3.74384, prediction/mean = 0.216801

Test set accuracy: 0.667
```

I have a suspicion that the `WARNING` steps are where my problem with the prediction lies even though the labels have already been booled, but have no clue what to do about it.

And, finally, pretty print gives me:

```
{'class_ids': array([1], dtype=int64),
 'classes': array([b'1'], dtype=object),
 'logistic': array([ 0.70525986], dtype=float32),
 'logits': array([ 0.87247205], dtype=float32),
 'probabilities': array([ 0.2947402 ,  0.70525986], dtype=float32)}
```

Full code can be found at https://github.com/llpk79/DNNTenThousand